# I am trying to make all classes (sometags) turn pink once I call it in javascript it has to be onClickEvent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make all classes called (sometags) turn pink once I have an onClickEvent in javascript.

1. sometags has to be stored in css
2. has to be on click event.

Thank you in advance for the help.

```js
function tag() {
  //document.getElementById("tag").onclick = someTags;
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "pink";

}
```

```css
<style>.someTags {
  color: pink;
}

</style>
```

```html
<h2 class="someTags">QUESTIONS:</h2>

<ol>
  <li id="questionOne" onMouseOver="mouseOverQ1()" onMouseOut="mouseOutQ1()">When 'mouseover' occurs on this question text, the font should become Courier.</li>
  <li id="questionTwo">When this text is double-clicked, a red double border 10px wide should appear. When double-clicked again, the border should disappear. (HINT: use rgb(x, y, z) for colours, not words.) Repeated double-clicks toggle between red border and no border.</li>
  <li id="questionThree" onclick="changeColor()">When this text is clicked the text should have a blue color. If clicked again, it should go green. Repeated clicks toggle the colour between blue and green.</li>
  <li id="questionFour" onMouseOut="mouseOutQ4()">When 'mouseout' occurs on this text, question 6 should have the text "Nothing to be done here" displayed.</li>
  <li id="q5" onclick="questionFive('chartreuse');" class="someTags">When this text is clicked, the background colour of the webpage becomes 'chartreuse'.</li>

  <li id="changeQ4" class="question6" class="someTags">Mouseover here will make the text disappear.</li>

  <li id="demo" class="someTags">When this text is clicked, change the background colour to pink of the first and third tags whose css class="someTags".</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: First of, stop using unsafe inline `on*` handlers. Use addEventListener instead. JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file. Create a [mcve], currently your code is full of missing functions.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I see thanks for the help. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score -1):

Here isa solution that i think can help.

```js
 const classElements = document.querySelectorAll(".someTags");
    const btnDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
    btnDemo.addEventListener('click', () =>
    {
      classElements.forEach(element => element.classList.add("green"));
    });
```

```css
    .green {
      background-color: pink;
    }
```

```html
<h2 class="someTags">QUESTIONS:</h2>

  <ol>
    <li id="questionOne" onMouseOver="" onMouseOut="">When 'mouseover' occurs on this question text, the font should become Courier.</li>
    <li id="questionTwo">When this text is double-clicked, a red double border 10px wide should appear. When double-clicked again, the border should disappear. (HINT: use rgb(x, y, z) for colours, not words.) Repeated double-clicks toggle between red border and no border.</li>
    <li id="questionThree" onclick="changeColor()">When this text is clicked the text should have a blue color. If clicked again, it should go green. Repeated clicks toggle the colour between blue and green.</li>
    <li id="questionFour" onMouseOut="">When 'mouseout' occurs on this text, question 6 should have the text "Nothing to be done here" displayed.</li>
    <li id="q5" onclick="questionFive('chartreuse');" class="someTags">When this text is clicked, the background colour of the webpage becomes 'chartreuse'.</li>

    <li id="changeQ4" class="question6" class="someTags">Mouseover here will make the text disappear.</li>

    <button id="demo" class="someTags">Button to click.</button>
  </ol>
```